# New GUI balance not showing?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I moved a good amount of monero from poloniex to the GUI. It looks like it is fully synced but it still shows my old balance. Confirmed the withdrawal on Polo and it is marked complete as of 45 min ago. I did not use a payment ID since I was sending it from polo to my own address. Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: I'm going to try to rebuild the cache in case it wasn't fully synced when I sent monero from Polo. Can't find my wallet folder with keys?

Comment: What OS?  If Windows the default location is C:\Users\(USERNAME)\Documents\Monero\wallets

Comment: I think this is because of one bug with the GUI (which will be fixed in the next relese). Deleting the cache and resyncing ought to fix it. Just make sure to not delete the .keys file by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Look up the transaction ID on a block explorer like [this one](http://moneroblocks.info/).  If it's found, then you'll know the transaction went through.  Then it's just a matter of making sure your node is fully synced and your wallet has synced to the daemon (node).

Comment: I get this message "whoops, looks like something went wrong"

Comment: If the transaction hash isn't on the blockchain on the first block explorer you check, then check other block explorers.  If no one has it (it's generally all or none, but just double check), then the transaction did not successfully send, and you'd have to ask Poloniex to look into it.

Comment: I found it on chainradar, but it just gives me 1 input and 2 outputs with the image and keys. Doesn't give me the amount or timestamp or anything. Should I try to rebuild the cache? I'm not able to find my wallet txt files in the GUI folder

Comment: I'm going to wait and see what support says. Thanks, your awesome. I'm still a noob, so help is always appreciated.